# Electron icns not showing up

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, electron, icns

I installed `electron-prebuilt` inside the main project root (locally).

I browse `node_modules/electron-prebuilt/` and i see the electron app package.

Then i show package contents and i browser `Resources/` where the app `atom.icns` can be found (i converted my atom.icns from an atom.png 1024x1024 file).

I replace `atom.icns` default icon with my own .icns naming it the same `atom.icons`
Then i move the app into another folder and then back to the original folder.

Pratically i followed these steps https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/654

Problem is that the icon does not appear i can only see a blank icon with a "disabled" figure on it like if the icon is missing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) suggested by Electron. Just pass your icon via `icon` option of electron-packager.